Was bedeutet "ja mal"?
Könntet ihr mir bitte sagen, was ja mal im Kontext unten bedeutet?

Person A: Schau mal Liebling. Unsere Betriebskostenabrechnung war im Briefkasten.
Person B: Oh, da bin ich ja mal gespannt.

Ich habe die Aussage in diesen Video gesehen, ab Sekunde 19.

Without giving your idea of ithe meaning, possibly supplemented by some reasons you arrived at it, this will likely be closed as translation request.

I don't need a translation. I need to understand what kind of meaning it conveys.

"ja" und "mal" sind Modalpartikeln. Die Bedeutung ist notorisch schwierig zu beschreiben, auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel ist nicht sehr hilfreich, weil dort allein schon Quellen fehlen.
Generell kann "ja" signalisieren, dass die Aussage nichts Neues sein soll, es gibt aber anscheinend auch andere Verwendungen (Dudengrammatik 2022, § 1506 ff.). Die Partikel "mal" signalisiert m.E. eine gelassene Haltung, sie taucht in vielen Wendungen auf, in denen man sich abwartend äußert, also nicht dringend handeln muss ("schauen wir mal"), oder in denen man keine starken Absichten hat oder die Handlung als beiläufig oder vorläufig hinstellt ("ich probier das mal"). Während z.B. "zeig mir das!" sogar drohend klingen kann, ist "zeig mal!" freundlich-beiläufig und gemäßigt neugierig.
Der Satz in der Frage "Da bin ich ja mal gespannt" signalisiert m.E. also in der wörtlichen Bedeutung zwar Neugier ("gespannt") aber eine wenig aktive, abwartende Einstellung und einen undramatischen Umgang mit der Sache. (Vielleicht sogar eine Absicht, die Sache mit Humor zu nehmen).

Dieses ja und das mal sind Modalpartikel.

Da bin ich gespannt.
Da bin ich ja gespannt. — Da bin ich gespannt, was dabei herauskommt.
Da bin ich mal gespannt. — Da bin ich gespannt, ob das klappt.
Da bin ich ja mal gespannt. — Da bin ich gespannt, ob etwas und was dabei herauskommt.


Danke für die Antwort. Es mir klar was "ja" transportiert, aber ich kann noch nicht verstehen, was "mal" bedeutet. Könnten Sir mir bitte noch eine weiter Erklärung schreiben?

Mal ist eigentlich kurz für einmal, aber als Modalpartikel bedeutet es eher so etwas wie Unsicherheit:einmal mag das richtig sein, aber nicht immer. Oft bedeutet es auch Beiläufigkeit: nebenbei, nicht hauptsächlich.

Janka, danke für die Erklärung. Könnten Sie mir gebe weiter Beispiele, wohin "einmal"  Unsicherheit transportieren würde. Ich finde es sehr schwere zu verstehen wie es Unsicherheit bedeuten kann

Mal sehen. — Warten wir ab, ob das klappt. Das will ich mal so stehen lassen. — Ich weiß nicht, ob das stimmt.

Modalpartikel transportieren oft auch gar keine Bedeutung, sondern verstärken einfach die Aussage des Satzes oder machen den Satz "lebendiger" oder "würziger". Deshalb werden sie bei Übersetzungen meist weggelassen. Hier verstehe ich "ja mal" wie: wirklich - zur Abwechslung. (Das ist ja interessant. = Das ist sehr interessant. = Dass das sooo interessant ist überrascht mich. = Das ist wirklich interessant und überraschend.) (Das ist mal interessant. = Endlich nicht nur langweiliges Zeug, wie sonst, sondern zur Abwechslung einmal auch was interessantes.) (ja mal = Das ist zur Abwechslung wirklich was interessantes und unerwartetes.)
